# double clicking on the batch file is not working as the filepath inside the script contains space

Tags: batch-file

Below is my batchscript.I saved the file with extension file.bat and I double clicked it. It does not show anything as the file path contains space (in `set file="C:\SUPPORT\APAC SIT\NewtextDoc.txt"`)

If I use `set file="C:\SUPPORT\APACSIT\NewtextDoc.txt"`  then it works.
If I use `set file="C:\SUPPORT\APAC SIT\NewtextDoc.txt"` then it does not work.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM  The below command will look for the size of file on the server and
     inform the user if scheduler is down.
setlocal  
set nl=^& echo.
set file="C:\SUPPORT\APAC SIT\NewtextDoc.txt"
set maxbytesize=0

FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% EQU %maxbytesize% (echo WARNING !!! %nl%Scheduler File is ^= 

%maxbytesize% bytes%nl%Please do not process invoices, contact Webcenter 
Support) else (echo Scheduler File OK)

PAUSE
```

Comment: I don't think I could grasp the idea entirely, but have you tried to escape the whitespace? Meaning to double quote the path containing spaces in your script `" "`.

Comment: PS `^` (caret) is another escape character as interpreted by the Command Prompt

Comment: in my batchscript,the path is
set file=="C:\SUPPORT\APAC SIT\NewtextDoc.txt"

Comment: when I am running the batch script through command window it is working by modifying the double quotes.
but if I double click on the bat file,it is not working

Comment: Have you tried to remove the double quotes from `set`'s assignment and escape the single instance of space by `^` character, as `APAC^ SIT`?

Comment: use the short name for your "APAC SIT" folder.  go to your command prompt, go into the "Support" folder .. then do:  dir /x APAC* ... the /x will give you long and short names.  The short is probably APAC~1 .. modify your path... C:\SUPPORT\APAC~1\NewtextDoc.txt

Comment: `FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA` or you could try  another approach`FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /B %file%') DO set size=%%~zA`

Comment: If I run the batch script from command window it is working but my requirement is,it has to work by double clicking on the batch file itself

Comment: What is the exact error message? Which line in the batch file fails? [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: set file="C:\SUPPORT\APAC SIT\NewtextDoc.txt"
As the file path contains space,it is failing to execute.

Comment: please note that I am not running from command window,i m just double clicking on batch file which I created(its my project requirement)

Comment: after I double clicking on the batch script,comman window opening and its closing within fraction of sec which even not able to see the error

Answer (score 0):

- [Escape strings containing `cmd` *poisonous* characters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in variables using double quotes **when defining variables**:

  - `set "_nl=& echo."`
  - `set "_file=path with spaces\name.ext"`
  - (there are a few rare circumstances only where is necessary another escaping schema)
- and then **use variables in a suitable way**:

  - unescaped: `echo WARNING !!!%_nl%Scheduler File is ^=%_size% bytes`
  - escaped: `FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ('"%_file%"') DO set "_size=%%~zA"`

Note that variable names defined in next script prefixed with a `_` low line (underscore) to make easy debugging, see `SET _&PAUSE` debugging (temporary) output.

**Commented script**:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
REM  The below command will look for the size of file on the server
REM                         and inform the user if scheduler is down.

set "_nl=& echo."                                  escape ampersand by double quotes
set "_file=D:\bat\odds and ends\a b\testfile.txt"  escape spaces using double quotes
rem set "_file=C:\SUPPORT\APAC SIT\NewtextDoc.txt" 

set "_maxbytesize=0"                    keep using double quotes even if unnecessary

if not exist "%_file%" (
    set /A "_size=_maxbytesize-1"
    echo "%_file%" does not exist
) else (
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN ('"%_file%"') DO set "_size=%%~zA"
)

echo debugging output should show variables _file, _maxbytesize, _nl, _size 
SET _&PAUSE

if %_size% LEQ %_maxbytesize% (
    echo WARNING !!!%_nl%Scheduler File is ^=%_size% bytes
    echo Please do not process invoices, contact Webcenter Support
) else (
    echo Scheduler File OK%_nl%"%_file%" filesize is %_size% bytes
)
PAUSE
```

**Output**:

```
==> rename "D:\bat\odds and ends\a b\testfile.txt" testfilea.txt

==> set _
Environment variable _ not defined

==> D:\bat\SU\1130895.bat
"D:\bat\odds and ends\a b\testfile.txt" does not exist
debugging output should show variables _file, _maxbytesize, _nl, _size
_file=D:\bat\odds and ends\a b\testfile.txt
_maxbytesize=0
_nl=& echo.
_size=-1
Press any key to continue . . .
WARNING !!!
Scheduler File is =-1 bytes
Please do not process invoices, contact Webcenter Support
Press any key to continue . . .

==> rename "D:\bat\odds and ends\a b\testfilea.txt" testfile.txt

==> D:\bat\SU\1130895.bat
debugging output should show variables _file, _maxbytesize, _nl, _size
_file=D:\bat\odds and ends\a b\testfile.txt
_maxbytesize=0
_nl=& echo.
_size=13
Press any key to continue . . .
Scheduler File OK
"D:\bat\odds and ends\a b\testfile.txt" filesize is 13 bytes
Press any key to continue . . .

==>
```